# What if a skydiver hits another parachute?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

So, hypothetical scenario: 2 Skydivers are falling, directly on top of and in close proximity to each other. The lower one opens his chute, while the upper one keeps falling. What happens? Does the upper diver impact the lower one? Does he block the parachute? Or is he simply pushed away by the airfilled cloth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any moment during the fall, the lower skydiver feels air resistance in the form of drag force, $D$, which in still air can be modelled as:

$$D=A\rho C_dv^2$$

$A$ is the frontal area (the area that must "push away" the air below), $\rho$ the density of air at the particular height, $C_d$ the drag coefficient which depends on body shape, and $v$ the falling speed.

The upper skydiver is in the slip stream and thus presumably feels a smaller drag force. He will thus expectedly fall faster and soon touch the lower skydiver. He will have to be farther above the lower skydiver and out of the relevant slip-stream zone to achieve the same drag force and fall equally fast (also assuming same body size, same composure and ignoring air density differences, winds etc.).

A parachute works in the manner that a when you pull the string to release the chute, a small so-called *pilot chute* is released first. It is small and does not significantly slow down the fall. Its purpose is to catch the air and perform a controlled upwards release of the main canopy. The canopy will then unfold and after some string work by the skydiver if necessary to unfold it fully, it will catch the air and slow down the fall.

The pilot chute will when released feel a drag force $D_\text{pilot}$. Due to its much lower mass, this drag force will drastically decelerate it. It will slow down, which means that it appears to move upwards relative to the skydiver (it doesn't move upwards, though, the skydiver just falls faster away from it). When the main canopy opens, it too will feel a drag force. This drag force will be much larger than that on the skydiver due to the larger frontal area and most importantly the difference in $C_d$ due to the new shape.

Now, purely mechanically, if the upper skydiver is so close to the lower skydiver that he is in the way of the pilot chute, then he might interrupt its release, buckle the chute, entagnle the strings or something else which will interrupt the entire canopy opening. Thus, the full size of the parachute will never actually open.

He could, though, avoid interrupting the pilot chute due to its small size. He will then fall past it while it is being slowed down. When the main canopy openes, we will not be able to avoid it. As the canopy due to its size will not fully open until a second later when the air has caught it, he might simply bump into the lumb of fabric and entangle himself in it. It might then never fully open and he, the parachute fabric and the other skydiver will continue their fall and the close-to the same speed as before - just this time with a tad more panic.

What, then, if he is higher up so that the parachute manages to fully open before he bumps into it? I don't think that will make much of a difference. Parachute fabric is very thin and light (yet strong) and my guess is that when he falls into it, he will lumb it up again. This just means that the lower skydiver will first feel a large deceleration as the canopy catches air but then will start fall fast again as the canopy is interrupted.

This would be my guess of how the scenarios might play out without having looked into testing of this sort. But there might be examples or tests on how the fabric will behave when impacted that can be found on the internet.